# After updating the metatag module I am unable to edit the metatag section of a taxonomy term

Tags: updating, meta-tags

Today I have updated the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module to the latest version (7.x-1.0). 
However, I try to edit the metatags of a taxonomy term and, after saving the change, nothing changes (it doesn't save the changes).

I have been researching into the issue and I have read that this can happen when the metatag module is not up to date.

A new development version (7.x-1.x-dev) has been released today. I have tried downloading and using the development version (7.x-1.x-dev) and I still have the same problem. Is the problem related with database corruption? What do I need to do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating to the latest version, there were a few issues in 1.0 that were fixed in subsequent releases.

Disclaimer: I'm the module's maintainer.